# Mongodb projection in Mysql 5.7 JSON

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Considering a collection containing documents like these ones:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "ppl": [
        { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Lennon",  "job": "singer" },
        { "first_name": "Eddy", "last_name": "Murphy",  "job": "actor"  },
        { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Goodman", "job": "actor"  }
    ]
},
{
    "foo": "bazinga!",
    "ppl": [
        { "first_name": "Dave", "last_name": "Gahan",   "job": "singer"   },
        { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Dalton",  "job": "chemist"  },
        { "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Goodman", "job": "TV actor" },
        { "first_name": "Eric", "last_name": "Dane",    "job": "actor"    }
    ]
}
```

How can I write the following MongoDB query using [MySQL JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html):

```
db.collection.findOne(
    { "foo": "bar", "ppl.last_name": "Goodman" },
    { "ppl.$.last_name": 1 }
)
```

which is expected to return 1 sub-record:

```
{ "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Goodman", "job": "actor" }
```

I'm having difficulties translating the MongoDB projection using MySQL syntax and your help would be appreciated.